# Twig check elements of array are in another array

Tags: twig

I'm trying to check in twig if any element of one array are set in other array.
Example:

I have user.roles with `['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MANAGER']` and I have the product.roles with `['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER']`.

I want to check (in Twig) if any user.roles are in product.roles, like:

```
{{ user.roles[0] is product.roles|keys }}
```

But with each element of user.roles in the same function.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the filter [`filter`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) to do this, but guessing it would be better to move this to `PHP` / `TwigExtension`

```
{% if user.roles |filter((role) => role in product.roles) | length > 0 %}
    Can do something with the post
{% else %}
    Access denied
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/hrk5ee)

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee!, that works! But finally I make a Symfony Voter to can use the is_granted in twig and in the controller :). But your solution works so well too :)

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it this way. The aproach you took is a far better one than doing this in pure twig

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
{% for role in user.roles %}
  {% if role in product.roles|keys %}
    do something...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If two or more roles are granted you would have multiple output with this